# IK rotation control question

Tags: animation, bones, constraints, drivers, inverse-kinematics

please see the picture below. there are 3 bones, bone A,bone B, and bone C.bone A is bone B's parent and bone A and bone B are connected. bone B has IK constraint and chain length is 2, target is bone C.If I move bone C, bone A and bone B bend like left picture, but I need them to bend like right picture.

[image]

I need bone B to bend fully, but bone A to bend at half degrees. For example when bone B bends at 50 degrees, bone A needs to bend at 25 degrees.I tried to edit bone A's Inverse Kinematics values in Bone Properties,but it doesn't work, and I added a driver to bone A and make it use bone B's rotation value(like "var/2" driver expression )but it causes dependency error and it breaks animation. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be a solution for you but it is not exactly BoneA.rotation = BoneB.rotation / 2

[image]

A dummybone is used for the IK constraint.
Bone A copies rotation of dummybone with half influence.
Bone B is parented to Bone A and damped tracked to dummybone to avoid dependencies.
[image]

Comment: thank you. my temporary solution is, bone B is child of bone A.bone A has damped track, target is bone C and bone B has IK, target is bone C and chain length is 1. damped track influence is 0.5. It may work like yours.